# How to make TextInput prefill in React Native app?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, mask, textinput

I have a TextInput component in my React Native app. And i need to make the field is pre-populated with a mask of 408xx810xxx, 1-3 and 6-8 digits in the field, their change is prohibited to put for users. Can somebody recommend the best way how can i do it?

```
          <TextInput
            style={[SS.input, styles.input]}
            placeholder={props.placeholder} placeholderTextColor={theme.inputPlaceholder}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent' editable={!props.disabled}
            keyboardType={props.keyboardType || 'default'} autoCapitalize={capitalize}
            keyboardAppearance={props.keyboardAppearance}
            autoCorrect={autoCorrect} selection={state.position}
            secureTextEntry={this.state.guarded}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChangeText={this._onChangeText}
            onFocus={this._onFocus} onBlur={this._onBlur}
            autoFocus={props.autoFocus}
            multiline={props.multiline}
            maxLength={props.maxLength}
            onContentSizeChange={onContentSizeChange}
          />
```

Comment: Can you impl 4 textfields 2 for noneditable & other 2 for editable. And bind them in one view.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great idea! i will try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pre-population, you can assign hardcoded masked value to the state `this.state.value` in your constructor.

And for masking I recommend you using this library:

> https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask

using this library masking work something like this

```
<TextInputMask
  refInput={ref => { this.input = ref }}
  onChangeText={(formatted, extracted) => {
  console.log(formatted) // +1 (123) 456-78-90
  console.log(extracted) // 1234567890
 }}
  mask={"+1 ([000]) [000] [00] [00]"}
```

/>

Comment: Thank you so much Danish 

Answer (score 3):

I have created a minimal example which exactly recreates your use case, without using any third party lib.

### Code

**changeText:**

```
changeText(text){
// we do not allow the deletion of any character
if (text.length >= 11){
  var tmp = text.split("")
  // check if there are still is a X value in string 
  const currentIndex = text.indexOf('X');
  if (currentIndex) {
    //if a X was found, replace it with the newest character
    tmp[currentIndex] = tmp[11];
    //remove latest character again
    tmp.pop();
  }
  this.setState({value: tmp.join("")})
  }
}
```

**render:**

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <TextInput
      value={this.state.value}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.changeText(text)}
     />
  </View>
```

### Working Demo

https://snack.expo.io/Sym-2W8RH

Comment: Tim thank you so much for the great answer  But if i need 20 characters in the field?

Comment: I think it is not user-friendly i.e. on UI

Comment: @Tejas of course this is not a perfect solution, it's just a working example. It gives a raw idea how the op can achieve such things by him-/herself.

Comment: @jocoders you would need to replace every `11` in my code with `20`. I would appreciate an upvote/marking it as accepted answer.

Comment: @jocoders By the way, you can accept an answer by clicking the check icon beside the answer (under the vote counter). By accepting an answer, you will also be rewarded with extra reputation.

Comment: thank you so much Tim for the info, but i still waiting a more decisions

Answer (score 0):

The best decision that i have found to use react-native-masked-text library:

```
import { TextInputMask } from 'react-native-masked-text';
```

```
            <TextInputMask
              type='custom' 
              options={{mask: accountMask}} 
              maxLength={20}
              customTextInput={InputText} 
              customTextInputProps={this._loginMaskProps}
              value={vm.checkingAccount} keyboardType={'number-pad'}
              placeholder={accountPlaceholder} 
              onChangeText={vm.changeCheckingAccount}
            />
```

You need just put property type to 'custom', and create a mask according https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text library, in my case it was like this:

```
 const accountMask = '40899810999999999999',
```